# A dataset for univariate nonparametric regression

Tags: data-request

Where can we find a publicly accessible real-life dataset for univariate nonparametric regression? A reviewer asked us to include an example with some real data. The problem is that there should be some way to estimate the "quality" of approximation in order to compare our method with known approaches. Otherwise what would be the profit in including real-life dataset computations?

Comment: As an example, can you describe a dataset that would meet your needs?

Comment: @csk I need a dataset for univariate nonparametric regression. Besides, I want to estimate somehow the accuracy of approximation. So, ideally, the data would be something like: time (or another independent variable), observed response value, real response value. The real response values may be given by a formula, or something like that.